# How to access a certain div that has a certain css property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do you access a certain `div` that has a certain CSS property?

**For example:**

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id=1 class="child"></div>
  <div id=2 class="child"></div>
  <div id=3 class="child"></div>
  . .
  <div id=50 class="child" style= "background:yellow;"></div>
  . . .
  <div id=100 class="child"></div>
</div>
```

So, how can I access the `div` with the `background: yellow` and retrieve its `id`?

The `div` with the yellow background changes to different `div` so will right this in jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `style="background:yellow"`, not "styles:". Anyway, this is how you can work with it:

```
const div = document.querySelector('div[style="background:yellow;"]').id;
```

Comment: This will work in the above case, but not if there are other css properties set in style, for example, it won't work if I have `<div id="50" style="background:yellow;color:blue">`

Comment: im getting a null from div, i only want thevalue of id though, is this the way to do it?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot to add on the `.id`, but if you're getting null, that means the selector is incorrect. Replace the `"style="background:yellow;"` bit with exactly what you have in your HTML, and it should be fine. Right now you have `styles: "background:yellow;"`, which is wrong. So whatever you correct that to, make sure it's reflected in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you've a typo in :

```
<div id=50 class="child" styles: "background:yellow;"></div>
______________________________^^^ //Must be singulare 'style' plus an equal like `style=`
```

You could select by the attribute `style` like `'div[style="background:yellow;"]'` :

```js
 console.log( $('div[style="background:yellow;"]').prop('id') );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id=1 class="child"></div>
  <div id=2 class="child"></div>
  <div id=3 class="child"></div>
  . .
  <div id=50 class="child" style="background:yellow;"></div>
  . . .
  <div id=100 class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**NOTE 1:** If there's more rules inside the `style` attribute value we could use contains selector `*=` like:

```
$('div[style*="background:yellow;"]').prop('id');
```

Comment: This will work in the above case, but not if there are other css properties set in style, for example, it won't work if I have `<div id="50" style="background:yellow;color:blue">`

Comment: Then we could use contain `*=` selector ...

Comment: Yes, naturally. You may want to update your answer to include this.

Comment: Shouldn't even be "styles". Should be singular.

Comment: Fixed, Thanks for your intervention...

Comment: it seems that i could not get it to work. i only need the value of the id, so does matchedDivs = 50 ?

Comment: No, it will return all the matched divs, so it will be better to use selector in this case ...